# Are free products of finite cyclic groups perfect?

Tags: group-theory

I read that $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_3$, which is a perfect group. Then, in general, for natural numbers $n$ and $m$, when is $\mathbb{Z}_n*\mathbb{Z}_m$ perfect? Is $\mathbb{Z}_n*\mathbb{Z}_{n+1}$ always perfect if $n\ge 2$?

Comment: Why do you think that $\;\Gamma:=PSL(2,\Bbb Z)\;$ is perfect? I don't recall exactly, but I'm almost sure that $\;\left|\Gamma/\Gamma'\right|=6\;\;or\;\;12\;$ ( I think it is the first one) .

Comment: It's not perfect.  There is an epimorphism onto the cyclic group of order $6$, which is $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: Ah, I misconceived something-_-.. yes, $\text{SL}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ is perfect, but $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ or $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is not. I was stupid.........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any groups $A$ and $B$ there is a surjective homomorphism $A\ast B\to A\times B$.  Therefore, if $m,n>1$, the infinite non-abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_m\ast\mathbb{Z}_n$ has the finite abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_m\oplus\mathbb{Z}_n$ as a homomorphic image, so cannot be perfect.